# How to restore palette in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

What I have tried:

I have tried windows > IDE tools > palette
The palette editor appears in a separate window in netbeans and I simply cannot click on that or drag anything.

I have reopened my project, it doesn't work

I have restarted netbeans, gave ctrl+shift+8, yet the palette editor is not in the proper place.

Edit:
I have fixed this.
In netbeans, the procedure is windows > reset windows

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://core.netbeans.org/proposals/reset-settings-ui-spec.html) out. there is a Reset palette to default settings section. 
Also if you mean that is on a pop-up window, try to right click it and Dock it. Netbeans allows you to reorder  windows, and make them float (Alt +Shift +D) documented [here](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/floating_windows/floating_windows.html).